# PHP Advanced Download Counter

Tags: php, download, counter

I am looking for a script that records the download after the download has finished, not just on link click which ensures that the file was actually downloaded and not cancelled after initializing it.

I have a feeling that this is going to be complicated but I am prepared to learn.

Comment: You've juxtapositioned yourself there mate. You want a script to do it for you, but you haven't tried to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Btw, `PHP` has no way of tracking the completion of a download. A solution for this is [Using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4168965/2518525)

Comment: You can do this by having PHP parse Apache's log files. If you want to go down that route, check the customlog docs, you probably want $X

Answer (score 2):

You can't really, unless...

1. Your download notifies your server on opening it (only possible for programs generally)
2. You make a guess at how long it may have taken to download

Both these options are terrible.